# Run a java class on click of a button

Tags: java, html, jsp

This is how my Main class looks like. I want to run this on press of the button in the jsp file.

```
package main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XmlParser b = new XmlParser();

        ServiceController sl = new ServiceController();

        Pipeline2 objPipeline2 = new Pipeline2();

        objPipeline2.main(args);

        b.parseXML();

        sl.callServiceByDomain();

    }

}
```

Comment: You will need ajax to make it if you don't wants to send the page request back.

Comment: Could you add some details on what you've tried, and what isn't working with the above code?